# Remove Div with a id from a string in javascript, without removing its content

Tags: javascript, html

I need to remove a  from a string in javascript. The content of the div should remain as it is, only div tag needs to be removed. For instance:

I have following similar string in javascript

`<div id='abc' style=''> abc fe <div id='someOtherId'>ghgh  </div>jjjj </div>`

i need the resultant string as

```
abc fe <div id='someOtherId'>ghgh  </div>jjjj
```

Thanks

Comment: What does your attempt at the code look like so far?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery, this can easily be done like this:

```
var textString = "<div id='abc' style=''> abc fe <div id='someOtherId'>ghgh </div>jjjj </div>";

var htmlObject = $(textString);
var innerHtml = htmlObject.html();
```

Edit: When not using jQuery, this should probably work as well

```
var textString = "<div id='abc' style=''> abc fe <div id='someOtherId'>ghgh </div>jjjj </div>";
var tempObject = document.createElement("div");
tempObject.innerHTML = textString;
var innerHtml = tempObject.firstChild.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div id='abc' style=''> abc fe <div id='someOtherId'>ghgh </div>jjjj </div>
<p></p>
<script>
    var content=$('#abc').hmtl();
    $('p').append(content);
</script>
```

[jsfiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/Shj8q/)
hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

Try By This Code:

```
<div id='abc' style=''> <span id="txttoshow">abc fe <div id='someOtherId'>ghgh </div>jjjj </div></span>
```

jquery code:

```
$('span').unwrap();
```